# Trying to make code work over classes

Tags: c++, sdl

I was trying to make this code work over different classes, It comes up with an empty 
window and then closes immediately.

main.cpp

```
//The Headers
#include "SDL_SCREEN.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

//The event structure
SDL_Event event;

int main (int argc, char* args[]){

    printf( "START" );    
    //The quit flag
    bool quit = false;

    //The Surface to be displayed
    SDL_Surface* dis = NULL;

    //The Screen Surface
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
    //The screen
    SDL_SCREEN screen_sdl;



    if ( screen_sdl.init( "TEST", screen ) == false )
    {
            return 1;
    }

    dis = screen_sdl.load_image( "a.png" );

    screen_sdl.apply_surface( 0, 0, dis, screen, NULL );

    if ( SDL_Flip ( screen ) == -1 )
    {
            return 1;
    }
    while ( quit == false )
    {
            //While there are events to handle
            while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
            {
                    //if the user has xed out the window
                    if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    {
                            //Quit the program
                            quit = true;
                    }
            }
    }

    screen_sdl.clean_up( dis, screen );
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

SDL_SCREEN.h

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

class SDL_SCREEN{    
        public:
            SDL_Surface *load_image( char* );
            void apply_surface( int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect* );
            bool init(char*, SDL_Surface*);
            void clean_up(SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*);
            void flip_screen (SDL_Surface* screen){
                    if ( SDL_Flip ( screen ) == -1)
                    {
                            printf( "BLAH" );
                    }
            }
};
```

SDL_SCREEN.cc

```
//The Headers
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_SCREEN.h"
#include <stdio.h>
//Screen atrabutes
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

SDL_Surface *SDL_SCREEN::load_image ( char *filename )
{
        printf( "LOADING" );
    //the image thats loaded
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;

    //The optimized image
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    //Load the image
    loadedImage = IMG_Load( filename );

    if ( loadedImage != NULL )
    {
            printf("Loaded");
            //Create the optimized image
            optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );

            //Free the old surface
            SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );

            //If the surface was optimized
            if ( optimizedImage != NULL )
            {
                    printf( " OPTIMIZED" );
                    //Color key the surface
                    SDL_SetColorKey( optimizedImage, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, SDL_MapRGB( optimizedImage->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );
            }


    }

    //return the optimized image
    return optimizedImage;
}

void SDL_SCREEN::apply_surface( int x, int y, SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL )
{

    //holds offsets
    SDL_Rect offset;

    //get offsets
    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    //blit
    SDL_BlitSurface( source, clip, destination, &offset );
}

void SDL_SCREEN::clean_up( SDL_Surface* to_clean, SDL_Surface* screen  )
{
    //Free the surfaces
    SDL_FreeSurface( to_clean );
    SDL_FreeSurface( screen );

}

bool SDL_SCREEN::init (char *Caption, SDL_Surface *screen)
{

    //Initialize all SDL subsystems
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING == -1 ) )
    {
            return false;
    }

    //set ut the screen
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );

    //if there was an error setting up the screen
    if( screen == NULL )
    {
            return false;
    }

    //set up the window caption
    SDL_WM_SetCaption( Caption, NULL );

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the form of a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org) in your question. Do not only link to it. The page you linked to will go away and your question will become useless to others.

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this :( and don't want to spend the next few minutes writing new code

Comment: Better you spend those few minutes than everyone who tries to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `init` only modifies the `screen` parameter, not the variable in main.
When you get to `apply_surface`, it's still `NULL`.
(And you would have found this out in seconds using a debugger.)

Your `SDL_Init` call also has a misplaced parenthesis - you're calling it with `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING == -1` instead of checking its return value.

Do it like this instead:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_SCREEN::init (char *Caption)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }   
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    if (screen != NULL)
    {
        SDL_WM_SetCaption( Caption, NULL );
    }
    return screen;
}
```

(Side note: since `SDL_SCREEN` doesn't hold any state, there's little point in making it a class.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a breakpoint before `SDL_Quit();` and try running it in debug mode.
Or use a getch() to force the program to display the output before it closes.

Comment: It only closed the terminal after adding scanf( char* )